# How to type check payload provided to action: React Typescript (React hooks)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have created a global context that will manage several of the UI states of my application. Currently the state just have only one property that will handle whether to show a Login view or a Signup view.

I have also typed the State and Action as following:

```
interface State {
  authView: AUTH_VIEWS
}

const initialState: State = {
  authView: 'LOGIN_VIEW',
}

type Action = {
  type: 'SET_AUTH_VIEW'
  view: AUTH_VIEWS
}

type AUTH_VIEWS = 'LOGIN_VIEW' | 'SIGNUP_VIEW'
```

Here is the action creator:

```
const setAuthView = (view: AUTH_VIEWS) => dispatch({ type: 'SET_AUTH_VIEW', view })
```

Since I have explicitly typed the type of views that should be accepted when passed as a payload to action, I have expected that there should be a **compile time error** or warning (from Typescript) in case wrong payload is passed or there is some typo, but that wasn't the case.

e.g. Show some error when following happens:

```
setAuthView('SIGNVIEW')    //typo
or
setAuthView('SOME_WRONG_PAYLOAD')
```

So the question is, how to correctly use Typescript to restrict the payload to correct type.

**Edit:**

Here is the code sandbox link for the complete code.
https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-context-c05d7

Following the discussion with Drag13, I suspect that the `setAuthView` is not correctly exported and that might be the reason for faulty typing when importing it in other component.

Comment: You must have misconfigured TypeScript. [in this playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMpjpZBvAUM5OAVzAAsA1YCAdwC5kBBAVQBUAJAfXIEkBRAdVS4AvrlwIA9iADOYZKGBhgcADbpMEeuqwBeHPkIkKVOsgDkAGQDyAcW4A5Ln35mANCLFgAngAcUDBCUpZD08Am8-ejNUXhYOZnYnATMDADcTegTOHgEhUVwI-1Zs51QQ82s7RxyXZAAfc1RuG3smAAUklzFJGTkAE2BpH0wEUnKACkQgkEzA4CkASh0APhAiFRUAbm6pWWRpCDAGI0oaCfSaTOLO1AWQ5eQBoZHScexkQqiYuKzOt2QLtRkMIFmIDkcTiZxpZbA4-ncAPQI5AgCTIaBQCRQXDg45kU7UaGoKwAWV4HH4ACUrPYbBw2gwAJrWBgAETMiORGKxOMOeOMNCJzXsNQ5yCR6KgmKgQA) you see that your example works as expected

Comment: @Taxel You are right, but this works only when the setAuthView is called within same file, i.e. the file containing the reducer. The function needs to be called from other components and its not working there.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as a codepen link or similar. There's not enough information in your question to see where you made a mistake. Also, `setAuthView` is not exported, so how do you pass the function into other components?

Comment: `State | any => any`. Using this construction you destroyed your types

Comment: @Drag13 I am fairly new to typescript. Can you please explain what needs to be corrected. Maybe you should post an answer.

Comment: @Taxel Can you help now? I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Drag13 pointed me to the right direction that the problem is with the type given to Context. Then after a lot of further researching and brainstorming I came up with this solution.

```
interface ContextProps {
  state: State
  dispatch: Dispatch<Action>
}

export const UIContext = createContext<ContextProps | undefined>(undefined)
```

The custom hook below does the undefined check

```
export const useUIContext = () => {
  const context = useContext(UIContext)
  if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error(`useUI must be used within a UIProvider`)
  }
  return context
}
```

```
export const UIProvider: FC = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(UIReducer, initialState)

  return <UIContext.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>{children}</UIContext.Provider>
}
```

Reading this blog https://kentcdodds.com/blog/how-to-use-react-context-effectively made me to ditch the action creator pattern and directly exposing the dispatch method for state mutation as with typescript and strongly typed Actions there is no need for the unnecessary abstraction of using the action creators.

Answer (score 0):

An issue is in this line of code:

```js
export const UIContext = createContext<State | any>(initialState)
```

Basically you are saying that type of your context can be `State` OR `any` which, at the end, means that your context can be `any`. Take a look into this simple example:

```js
const sum = (a:number, b: number | any) => a+b;
sum(1,1); // works
sum(1, 'i am not a number!!!'); // still works because b can be any :(
```

First example works as expected, but the second also works, because b can be anything!

To fix your issue you should return any from declarations:

```js
export const UIContext = createContext<State>(initialState)
```

The simplest fix will be looks like this:

changing State type to support `setAuthView` function

```js
interface State {
  authView: AUTH_VIEWS;
  setAuthView: (e: AUTH_VIEWS) => void;
}
```

Providing dummy realization for `setAuthView` to make TS happy (a bit ugly, yes)

```js
const initialState: State = {
  authView: "LOGIN_VIEW",
  setAuthView: () => void 0,
};
```

Now it should work and check your types correctly

I would also recommend to read about the [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) this will helps you pretty much.

Comment: See the demo here https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-context-c05d7.
If I remove any, then in index.ts I get this error - Property 'setAuthView' does not exist on type 'State'

Comment: This is intentional, because your type state doesn't have `setAuthView` :) Ill try to update the answer

Comment: I suspect ```setAuthView``` needs to be exported in some other way. Will be great if you can work this out

Comment: Yeah this works, but it is still a hack. There's gonna be a lot more action creators  like ```setAuthView``` and this is definitely not the approach I would like to follow.

Comment: If you want to use context as a Store, I am not sure you have other option. Might be it will be better to switch to the MobX or Redux?

Answer (score 0):

I think the other answer explains your mistake quite well, but since you were not sure how to structure a `Context` with `useReducer` and `TypeScript`, here is how I do it. Feel free to copy-paste this and fit it to your needs.

```js
import { createContext, Dispatch, FC, useReducer } from "react";

// how is the state structured?
interface DemoContextState {
  selectedArtNr: string;
  featureEnabled: boolean;
  externallySelected: boolean;
}

// actions are a discriminated union. They all have a 'type' but can have differing payloads or none at all
type DemoContextActions = {
  type: "SET_SELECTED_ARTNR";
  payload: {
    artnr: string;
    externallySelected?: boolean;
  };
} | {
  type: "TOGGLE_FEATURE";
};

const initialState: DemoContextState = {
  selectedArtNr: "",
  featureEnabled: false,
  externallySelected: false,
};

// our context will be made up of state and dispatch.
export const DemoContext = createContext<{state: DemoContextState, dispatch: Dispatch<DemoContextActions>}>({state: initialState, dispatch: ()=>{}});

// our reducer. Here we define all state transitions
const demoContextReducer = (state: DemoContextState, action: DemoContextActions): DemoContextState => {
  switch(action.type){
  case "SET_SELECTED_ARTNR": {
    const selectedArtNr = action.payload.artnr;
    const externallySelected: boolean = action.payload.externallySelected || false;
    return {...state, selectedArtNr, externallySelected};
  }
  case "TOGGLE_FEATURE":
    return {...state, featureEnabled: !state.featureEnabled};
  default:
    // TS will throw a compile time error if you've defined actions that are not handled
    const exhaustiveCheck: never = action;
    throw new Error(`Unhandled action: ${action}`);
  }
};

// use this context provider high up in the component tree
export const DemoContextProvider: FC = ({children})=>{

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(demoContextReducer, {...initialState});
  
  return (
    <DemoContext.Provider value={{state, dispatch}}>
      {children}
    </DemoContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

As you can see, I pass an object with two variables in my context: `state` and `dispatch`.

You can use it like so:

```
// in component
const {state, dispatch} = useContext(DemoContext);
// do whatever you want with state and dispatch. If you just need to show the current state, just destructure state. If you just need to mutate the state, just destructure dispatch
```

Comment: This approach is the way to go. I was just about to post my answer as well that too follows this pattern.